# REST Routes & Verbs - Handling routes without a parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, api, http, rest, routes

#### Background

I wrote an REST-like API service controller for a simple Blog app. I use two routes to handle basic CRUD:

```
// Actions should handle: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
routes.MapRoute("Api-SingleThing", "thing/{id}",
    new { controller = "ThingService", action = "SingleThing" });

// Action should handle: GET
routes.MapRoute("Api-AllThings", "things",
    new { controller = "ThingService", action = "AllThings" });
```

The matching controller code looks like:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AllThings() {}

[HttpGet]
[ActionName("SingleThing")]
public ActionResult Get(string id) {}
    
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("SingleThing")]
public JsonResult Create(Thing thing) {}
    
[HttpPut]
[ActionName("SingleThing")]
public ActionResult Update(Thing thing) {}

[HttpDelete]
[ActionName("SingleThing")]
public ActionResult Delete(int id) {}
```

The `[ActionName()]` attribute is used to avoid route constraints, so that the route when triggered always calls the "SingleThing" action on the controller - regardless of the HTTP verb. This lets the controller action methods that share the name, decide who handles the request based on the `[HttpVerb]` attributes.

In my blog app, this works like a charm, but only because the `{id}` route parameter (aka. the slug) is always present, even on `POST` and `PUT` requests.

With this new API shown above, the `POST` and `PUT` actions do not trigger the top route (ex. no `{id}` value), and when they trigger the second route, there is no method to handle them because of the verbs.

#### Question

What's the best way to maintain this REST-ful URL architecture and verb handling, and ensure I trigger my POST and PUT actions?

Comment: ASP.NET WebApi is much better at REST. Why don't you give it a try instead?

Comment: @jgauffin i would use it, and have goofed around with it, but it's not release yet, no? 4.5 framework? my company is a worrywart about "bleeding edge" tech... mvc3 is still brand new in their eyes.