# How to route PUT and DELETE requests for the same url to different controller methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I was searching for an answer to this question, and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2143884/304832), which is indeed very similar. However the solutions(s) posted there don't seem to be working for me... I wonder if it has to do with the question's age.

Given the following URL:

```
/my/items/6
```

I want HTTP PUT requests for this URL to be handled by one action method, and HTTP DELETE requests to be handled by another action method. Below are the routes I defined (note these are based in an area, so `context` is an `AreaRegistrationContext` instance, if that matters):

```
context.MapRoute(null,
    "my/items/{id}",
    new { area = "AreaName", controller = "ControllerName", action = "Replace" },
    new
    {
        httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST", "PUT"),
    }
);

context.MapRoute(null,
    "my/items/{id}",
    new { area = "AreaName", controller = "ControllerName", action = "Destroy" },
    new
    {
        httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST", "DELETE"),
    }
);
```

URL generation works fine with both of these routes, however there are problems when routing incoming requests. Only the first-declared route correctly maps to its respective action.

I dug into the `HttpMethodConstraint` source code and discovered that it does not care about the `"X-HTTP-Method-Override"` parameter, only `HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod`.

I was able to solve this problem with the following custom route constraint class:

```
public class HttpMethodOverrideConstraint : HttpMethodConstraint
{
    public HttpMethodOverrideConstraint(params string[] allowedMethods) 
        : base(allowedMethods) { }

    protected override bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, 
        string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, 
        RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        var methodOverride = httpContext.Request
            .Unvalidated().Form["X-HTTP-Method-Override"];

        if (methodOverride == null)
            return base.Match(httpContext, route, parameterName, 
                values, routeDirection);

        return 
            AllowedMethods.Any(m => 
                string.Equals(m, httpContext.Request.HttpMethod, 
                    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            &&
            AllowedMethods.Any(m => 
                string.Equals(m, methodOverride, 
                    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        ;
    }
}
```

...and these route definitions:

```
context.MapRoute(null,
    "my/items/{id}",
    new { area = "AreaName", controller = "ControllerName", action = "Replace" },
    new
    {
        httpMethod = new HttpMethodOverrideConstraint("POST", "PUT"),
    }
);

context.MapRoute(null,
    "my/items/{id}",
    new { area = "AreaName", controller = "ControllerName", action = "Destroy" },
    new
    {
        httpMethod = new HttpMethodOverrideConstraint("POST", "DELETE"),
    }
);
```

**My question: is it really necessary to have a custom route constraint to accomplish this?** Or is there any way to make it work out-of-the-box with standard MVC & routing classes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [REST Routes & Verbs - Handling routes without a parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543685/rest-routes-verbs-handling-routes-without-a-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Action filters are your friend...

[HttpDeleteAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpdeleteattribute.aspx), [HttpPutAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpputattribute.aspx), [HttpPostAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httppostattribute.aspx), [HttpGetAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpgetattribute.aspx)

Comment: Yes, my action methods are already decorated with [HttpPut] and [HttpDelete]. Makes no difference.

Comment: Then get rid of the routes and add an `ActionName` attribute to the action methods.

Comment: I don't understand how an `ActionNameAttribute` would help the action method selector better match the routes with the action methods. Can you point to any other references backing your rationale for `[ActionName(...)]`?

Comment: See the link that I flagged as a duplicate above.